# How to find electric potential from electric field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

[image]

How to find potential difference when electric field is given ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like, in general, $\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial y}\neq\frac{\partial E_y}{\partial x}$, so $\overrightarrow{E}$ cannot be a gradient of any decent function. Therefore, I don't think the problem has an unambiguous answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

$$\vec{E}=-\frac{\partial\vec{V}}{\partial x}\widehat{i} -\frac{\partial\vec{V}}{\partial y}\widehat{j}-\frac{\partial\vec{V}}{\partial z}\widehat{k} $$